# PayPal Sandbox Transaction Numbers but No Transactions

Tags: paypal

I'm using PayPal's Adaptive Payments API to pay people from my site. In the PayPal Sandbox (for testing of course), I'm getting PayPal Transaction numbers and dates back from the API calls, but when I check the test accounts, there is no change in money, and no recorded transaction(s).

If there is a transaction number, shouldn't there be a corresponding transaction? Why would I be getting a transaction number with no actual transaction occurring?

UPDATE: The following is my payment function that calls the PayPal API:

```
ReceiverList receiverList = new ReceiverList { receiver = new List<Receiver>() };
Receiver receiver = new Receiver(amountToPay) { email = receiverEmail };
receiverList.receiver.Add(receiver);

RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
const string actionType = "PAY";
const string returnUrl = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment/dotnet?success=true";
const string cancelUrl = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment/dotnet?cancel=true";
const string currencyCode = "USD";

PayRequest payRequest = new PayRequest(
    requestEnvelope,
    actionType,
    cancelUrl,
    currencyCode,
    receiverList,
    returnUrl)
{
    senderEmail = "SENDER_EMAIL_HERE"
};


_payPalConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"mode", "sandbox"},
    {"account1.apiUsername", "USERNAME_HERE"},
    {"account1.apiPassword", "PASSWORD_HERE"},
    {"account1.apiSignature", "SIGNATURE_HERE"},
    {"account1.applicationId", "SANDBOX_APP_ID_HERE"}
};

AdaptivePaymentsService adaptivePaymentService = new AdaptivePaymentsService(_payPalConfig);
PayResponse payResponse = adaptivePaymentService.Pay(payRequest);

if (!payResponse.error.Any())
{
    PaymentDetailsRequest paymentDetailsRequest = new PaymentDetailsRequest(new RequestEnvelope("en_US"))
    {
        payKey = payResponse.payKey
    };

    adaptivePaymentService = new AdaptivePaymentsService(_payPalConfig);
    PaymentDetailsResponse paymentDetailsResponse =
        adaptivePaymentService.PaymentDetails(paymentDetailsRequest);

    return paymentDetailsResponse.responseEnvelope;
}
return payResponse.responseEnvelope;
```

Here is where I deal with the response envelope:

```
ResponseEnvelope payResponse = ppa.SendPayment(payPalUserEmail, commissionAmount);

if (payResponse.ack.ToString() == "SUCCESS")
{
    payment.PayPalTrxNumber = //??
    payment.PayPalTrxDate = DateTime.Parse(payResponse.timestamp);
}
```

I realize I was using Correlation ID as my transaction number...not sure why, but that would account for the weirdness in the transaction number. But where do I get the transaction number on successful payment?

EDIT2: Thinking about it, though, I'm making it inside the `if (payResponse.ack.ToString() == "SUCCESS")` check, so doesn't this imply a successful payment?

Comment: The ACK simply means the API call was successful.  It doesn't mean any money has actually moved.  This depends on how the call was setup, whether an e-check was used, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need to see a sample of your API request and response to know more, but one example of how this could happen is if you're sending a Pay request with the ActionType set to CREATE.  This would generate a pay key (which is what I think you must be referring to as a transaction ID in this case) but no money would be moved until you follow that up with a call to the ExecutePayment API.

That's just one example, though.  Another reason could be that you're looking at the wrong sandbox account(s), which I've seen a lot of times quite frankly.

Again, it's tough to say without seeing your request.

Comment: I am using the "PAY" ActionType, but I realized I was using the correlation ID where I needed the transaction ID, which makes no sense. Not sure why I did that, but where can I get my transaction ID then? I've updated the question with my code.

Comment: You should just be using the PayKey.

Comment: Where is the PayKey located? I can't find it in the objects I have.

Comment: The PayKey would come back in the Pay API response.  It looks like you're already saving it to a variable:  payKey = payResponse.payKey

Comment: Oh! Okay, so I should be using that PayKey to get the transaction? Or is that the transation?

Comment: At the application level, that is your transaction number.  The actual receiver of the payment(s) would have a different transaction ID associated with their transaction, but you won't see that unless you are also the receiver and you have IPN configured.  Otherwise, you need to work with the Pay Key.

Comment: If I want to pass the transaction number of a user's purchase back to them, I need to have IPN configured?

Comment: Well, if you add the IPNNotifcationURL parameter to your Pay request, the IPN sent there will be application specific and won't contain much detail about the payment itself.  The receiver PayPal account would need to have IPN setup in order to obtain details like the transaction ID.  If you provide the PayKey, though, the buyer should be able to find their transactions with that just like the transaction ID.